# Handling rapid microtransactions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm running across an issue where innoDB locks rows while doing updates. When I run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` I end up getting tons of sleeping executions that look like this:

```
UPDATE accounts SET account_balance = account_balance + 0.000004514 WHERE account_id = 1234 LIMIT 1
```

The row gets lock and the server ends up with a traffic jam of update connections.

How do I scale my mySQL application, so that I can handle rapid micro-transactions?

EDIT: Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_balance` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `account_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2756 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Do you need that LIMIT 1?

Comment: Well, strictly not but I'm utterly paranoid about a colleague missing their morning coffee and making a bad keystroke on our production server.

Comment: may you show accounts table structure by "show create table accounts;"

Comment: @ZafarMalik added. There's some other columns I omitted, that just contain non-indexed account metadata.

Comment: It seems you are trying to update same primary key multiple times/very frequently....as innodb uses row level locking so your row will be locked..you need to check your requirement why same row is updating so frequently and how can avoid it.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a buffer instance that would have multiple rows updating - that would occasionally sum up all the totals into the master instance......would that help?

Comment: Also, one thing I just did was I deleted the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column - that seems to have helped a lot....